# Unable to position font-awesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using an icon from the font-awesome set. It is a bare minimum UX, where I am trying to position the icon on the right by using `float`. However, it does not float, and stays at its position. Even using other constructs like `position = relative` followed by adding values like `100px` for `top` and `left` it does not alter its position.

Can anyone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvwbt35z/).

Comment: You need to target the `svg` and not the `i` element. https://jsfiddle.net/r48qgn2s/

Comment: As I tested your code, I realized that you're using Font-awsome ``script``, so you select it as ***svg.fa-caret-left***. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Font-awsome `script`(*SVG*)(bottom of the *body* tag), then you should select it in CSS like this,

```
svg.fa-bars {
  float: right;
}
```

but if you're using Font-awsome `link`(*CSS*)(inside the *header* tag), then you should select it like this,

```
i.fa-bars {
  float: right;
}
```

you can also try Developer tools and then you'll see that the icon is shown as `<svg>`.

Comment: Remember that the first part of the class e.g. ***fas*** or ***fa*** e.g.(fas fa-bar), you should not select it as a selector in CSS cause it gets removed automatically in ``svg``. And if it doesn't get removed, then everything will be messed up.

Comment: Works. One question: the difference in size between `sm` and `lg` is too big. Can't we specify the font explicitly in pixels?

Comment: Of course you can. Simply add ``font-size`` in the selector in your css file, e.g. ``svg { font-size: 15px; }``.

Comment: Yup, it works. It wasn't working earlier. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Just Target SVG Element and you will get your desire output.

```
svg {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
}
```